# Looking for a Looney Tunes movie/episode

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation, identify-this-episode, looney-tunes

I'm looking for a Looney Tunes movie or an episode I recall watching as kid about ten years ago. Could you help me finding its name?

The scenes I remember are as follows:

- The plot consists of a character stealing [Scottish Kilts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilt) and later painting the entire world with colors extracted from the Kilts.
- The characters include `Marvin the Martian` and `Hector the Bulldog`. To my knowledge, it also includes `Sylvester`, `Tweety`, and `Granny`.
- One scene I remember clearly is the characters arriving in some kind of a Hotel or a residing place for vacation, and there is a scene in which Marvin's lab is shown.
- I remember another scene with `Daffy Duck` and `Porky Pig` where they're in another planet, and they find different rocks which gives them superpowers (Porky is portrayed as really buff when using them, but Daffy is unfortunate to find something useless.) And both of them are in some kind of a suit. I don't know if it's the same movie/episode, but I'd be grateful if you could find anything relatable to it.

As for the identifiable information:

- It's a color cartoon.
- The release date is before 2007ish.
- Unfortunately I don't recall if it was a feature length, or a series episode.

I hope I've provided enough information to get the name of the movie/episode, it's really dear for me to find. Any help finding it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the information you have given, it looks like a short pilot episode named [*Duck Dodgers in 24½ Century*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Dodgers_in_the_24%C2%BDth_Century) which was released in the year 1953. It stars Daffy duck as the main role an porky pig is the assistant. There are [five sequels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Dodgers_in_the_24%C2%BDth_Century#Sequels) based on this short pilot episode. So I think you are getting confused about the episodes involving those characters.

From the wikipedia page:

> Duck Dodgers in the 24½th Century is a 1952 Merrie Melodies color cartoon from Warner Bros., first released on July 25, 1953, that stars Daffy Duck as space hero Duck Dodgers, Porky Pig as his assistant, and Marvin the Martian as his opponent. This cartoon marked the first of many appearances of the Duck Dodgers character.

**The episode you mentioned:**

The episode you are talking about is *Pig of action/K-9 Kaddy* which is sixth episode in the series *[Duck Dodgers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Dodgers_(TV_series))*  which is one of the sequels aforementioned to the 1953 classic cartoon. This TV series is distributed by Warner Bros.

You can check the list of episodes of Duck dodgers [here](http://looneytunes.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Duck_Dodgers_episodes).

Below is a clip of the episode where Porky pig turns buffy.